# How to open a notebook from github in colab enterprise?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I found a notebook in Colab that I want to open in Colab Enterprise.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/gee-community/geemap/blob/master/docs/workshops/G4G_2023.ipynb#scrollTo=v3w_QO0miPZf

I can't see how to load a notebook from Github into Colab Enterprise.
What is the best way to do it? I know I can copy it to drive, but my organisation doesn't have drive attached to Colab Enterprise.